# Accurate cut of mp4 file using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to cut mp4 video to seperate videos by seconds 
in the example:

```
00:00:00 - 00:00:01
00:00:01 - 00:00:02
00:00:02 - 00:00:10.01
```

This is the commands I used:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 10sec.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:01 -async 1 -strict -2 -c copy 0002.mp4
ffmpeg.exe -i 10sec.mp4 -ss 00:00:01 -t 00:00:02 -async 1 -strict -2 -c copy 0003.mp4
ffmpeg.exe -i 10sec.mp4 -ss 00:00:02 -t 00:00:10.01 -async 1 -strict -2 -c copy 0004.mp4
```

And the files I got are:
1.3 second long
2.6 second long
8.5 second long

So obviously the cutting it's not accurate...

I understand it's hes something to do with the key frame, so I want to decompress the original file (mpeg with very high quality) to be not compress at all (so every frame will be key frame) and then do the cutting on it (so now the cutting will be accurate)

The reason accuracy is so important to me is because after the cutting I must rejoin the slices to the single movie, and currently I just have replication in the movie I create from the slices.

I tried the .avi version:

```
..\ffmpeg.exe -i 10sec.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -acodec copy uncompressed.mp4
```

it's obviously failed duo to :

```
 [mp4 @ 091f1300] Could not find tag for codec rawvideo in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
 Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
 Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

So my q. is, how can I accurate slice a file using `ffmpeg` (I have the `pkt_pts` as well as the time I want to slice at, so if it's possible to accurate cut by `pkt_pts` it also will helkp me)?

Answer (score 0):

The error says MP4 doesn't support uncompressed video. So you better use AVI container and specify the pixel format:

> ..\ffmpeg.exe -i 10sec.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -acodec
> copy uncompressed.avi

Then you can frame/time accurately cut the uncompressed.avi file.

This is how it works for me:

1. Cut video-only parts from original video (Imagine.mp4) using loss-less transcoding

> ffmpeg -i Imagine.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.00 -t 00:00:05 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -an Imagine_part0.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -i Imagine.mp4 -ss 00:00:05.00 -t 00:00:05 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -an Imagine_part1.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -i Imagine.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.00 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -an Imagine_part2.mp4

2. Join parts without re-encoding

> ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -an -c:v copy -fflags +genpts Imagine_joined.mp4

3. Add only audio from original file to joined video and create final output (video + audio)

> ffmpeg -i Imagine_joined.mp4 -i Imagine.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest -fflags +genpts Imagine_final.mp4

Between step #1 and #2 you would usually do your encoding into the target quality but I've left this out for simplicity.

Comment: It's resulting with HUGE file (from 22 mb to 3.4gb) it's not very scalable solution for a full size movie (source of full video is 12gb...), do you have an idea for a more scalable solution?

Comment: on addition it's looks like I still don't get an accurate cuts :(

Comment: It's not possible to cut video at non-keyframes without partial decoding or re-encoding. You either have to cut at keyframes or do decoding.

Comment: Try without audio. Depending on the audio format ffmpeg may not cut accurately. You can add audio later to the rejoined video.

Comment: I accept it, but why I get files that are not consistence? how can I generate splits that can be rejoin to the exact orig video? (I accept non accurate place of cutting as long each cut is in the correct place (just after the last slice))

Comment: Have you tried without audio as I mention in my previous comment?

Comment: I think so, can you please share example of splitting like this?

Comment: ..\ffmpeg.exe -i 10sec.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -an uncompressed.avi

Comment: When saving CPU power is important, for cutting a time-accurate segment into uncompressed you use: ffmpeg -i your-source.mp4 - -to 00:00:05 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -an out.avi

When disk space is more important than CPU power, for cutting a time-accurate segment into loss-less compressed H264:
ffmpeg -i your-source.mp4 - -to 00:00:05 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -an out.mp4

Comment: it's didn't help, the file is still not cut accuratly

Comment: Can you please upload an example of small mp4 you cut to 3 slice and then rejoin them and the rejoin file is the same as the original?

Comment: How do you measure length of the output files?

Comment: I concnate all using `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4`  or `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy output.avi`and watch it, the video is 12 sec. now instead of 10 and it's clearlly overlaps and repeat some of the data

Comment: I've added more examples to my answer above.